# Connecting two classes java object-oriented

Tags: java, class, object

I wish to make two new classes, where I can connect these.
I want to create a player and team class. My goals is to assign a player to a team. Basically I wish to use a class within a class as attribute.

I imagine my player class be like;

```
public class Player {
    String first_name;
    String last_name;
    int age;
}
```

and my team to be something like;

```
public class Team {
    String Member1;
    String Member2;
}
```

and my main class to include;

```
Player Player1 = new Player("Peter", "Jensen", 24);
```

So what I want to do is calculate the average age of my players in a specific team. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: Your `Team` class should store `Player` objects, not `String` objects. You should also store them in some sort of collection instead of `member1`, `member2`, etc...

Comment: 1. Your classes are missing constructors  2. You could just add attribute `List<Player>` in your Team class instead of String attributes 3. Which average?

Comment: Your Team object needs a list of Players and not string names. Then loop through the players adding up their ages and divide that by the total player size.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My solution

```
public class Team {
List<Player> allPlayer;

// constructor, getter and setters
}
```

and

```
public class Player {
String name;
// constructor, getter and setters
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Rather than a single Player, perhaps a List of players.

Comment: Yes, like
    `public class Team  {
    List<Player> allPlayers; 
}`

Comment: And to be clear I did not mean to connect to classes but use the a class within a other class.

Answer (score 5):

In real life what is a team? it's a bunch of players so you need to make `Team` consist of `Players`, after that ask a question "where is a biggest amount of information to fulfill computation of average players age?" This  information placed inside of the `Team` class (players list) and we need to place method that calculate average age to `Team` class. It's called *information expert* principle, one of the many good oop design principles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_expert

So in this way code will be like that:

Player class:

```
  public class Player {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age; 

        public Player(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public String firstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public String lastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public String age() {
            return age;
        }

    }
```

Team class:

```
  public class Team {
        private List<Player> players;

        Team(List<Player> players) { 
           this.players = players;
        }

        public void add(Player player) {
            players.add(player);
        }

        public void remove(Player player) {
            players.remove(player);
        }

        public double averageAge() {
            double sum = 0;
            double amount = players.size();
            for (Player player : players) {
                sum += player.age();
            }
            return sum / amount;
        }

    }
```

after that we able to use this classes in every convenient way, example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Team team = new Team(Arrays.asList(new Player[] {
            new Player("Peter", "Jensen", 24),
            new Player("Foo", "Bar", 50)
        }));
        System.out.println(team.averageAge()); // 37
    }
}
```

Simple *ask* to team what is average players age, and team will respond to you.

Answer (score 3):

create a List or an array of players (if there is a fixed number of players allowed) inside the `Team` class to represent *the team of players*.

Example:

```
class Team {
   private List<Player> players = new ArrayList<>();

   public void setPlayers(List<Player> players){
          this.players = players;
   }

   public List<Player> getPlayers(){
       return Collections.unmodifiableList(players);
   }
}
```

then create your List of objects:

```
Team team = new Team();
team.setPlayers(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList( new Player("Peter", "Jensen", 24),
                new Player("Danny", "peters", 19),
                new Player("Michael", "Jones", 32))));
```

then you can calculate the average age like so:

```
double averageAge = team.getPlayers()
                        .stream()
                        .mapToDouble(Player::getAge)
                        .average().orElse(0); // 0 if no player present in the list
```

*note* - the example above uses a list but you could as easily just use an array, it also uses the streams API and if you're not familiar with it then you can do it like this:

```
double averageAge = 0; // default if no player is present
List<Player> players = team.getPlayers();
for (Player player : players) {
     averageAge += player.getAge();
}

if(players.size() >= 1) {
    averageAge /= players.size();
}
```

---

if for some reason you also want the ability to add a given player at a time then you can create a `void addPlayer(Player player){...}` method inside the `Team` class to take a given player and add it to the list of players.

Comment: You should also show how to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: @JohnManko using `BigDecimal` is unnecessary for this task.

Answer (score 1):

In your team you need to store a collection of players:

```
public class Team{
    private List<Player> players;

    public Team() {
        players = new ArrayList<?>();
    }

    public void addPlayer(Player player) {
        players.add(player);
    }

    public Int getAverageAge() {
        Int count =0;
        Int sumAge=0;
        for(Player player:players) {
            sumAge+=player.getAge();//this getter should be in Player class
            count++;
        }
        return sumAge/count;
    }
}
```

Use the addPlayer() method to add your player to the list in main class

Answer (score 0):

You can add getter and setter method to player class.Also if you want you can do something like this in player class:

```
public static Player newInstance(String n,String Sn,int age){
    Player a=new Player(n,Sn,age);
    return a;
```

}

Now you can easily add player to team.But members cant be String.My advice use ArrayList.You can find many articles about that.

And you can use 'for(Player a:ListName)'it will make your things easier.